# How to catch errors from REST service?

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP rest service. Many errors cause the PHP to terminate without giving any insight into the cause. Surrounding my functions in try catch clauses don't help, the script exits without entering the catch block. Is there a way to catch all/any errors in my PHP scripts?

Comment: Check your error log and see what error it is, most likely a `FATAL`. You can [set a custom error handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) to log these for you as well as using the [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Comment: Which version of php do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `error_log`. Most likely it's a `PHP FATAL` error that is being thrown before an `Exception` so it's dead before the `catch` statement.

To log everything, [register a shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in your application together with [`error_get_last()`](http://php.net/error_get_last). For example, this will log all error that will cause your application to unexpectedly die.

```
function shutdown()
{
    $arrError = error_get_last();

    if( is_null($arrError) ) {
        return true;
    }

    //Remove the if statement and just have the error_log() if you want to log everything
    if( in_array($arrError['type'], array(E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR, E_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR)) ) { //FATAL HANDLER!
       error_log("Error caught. ". $arrError['message'] ." in file ". $arrError['file'] .":". $arrError['line']);

       //Then maybe do something to make this verbose in your development environment
       if( ENVIRONMENT == "dev" ) {
           echo "<h3>ERROR</h3> ". $arrError['message'] ." in file ". $arrError['file'] .":". $arrError['line'];
           die;
       }
    }

}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```